# strstr() function in PHP is not working whatsoever

Tags: php, strstr

I'm running PHP 5.3.8 on my local, 5.2.17 on my remote.

strstr() works fine on my local, but when loaded in remote it returns nothing. Even error reporting doesn't say anything.

A simple use of it:

```
echo strstr('1234567890', '3', true);
```

should return 12. Instead gives nothing. I'm lost for ideas at this point. How could two identical scripts return different results?

Is it secretly turned off? Or is there a setting I don't know about? Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: On PHP 5.2.17, there is no third parameter!

Comment: I've tested your code and got `12` as I was supposed to get.

Comment: `echo '*'; echo strstr('1234567890', '3', true); echo '*';` - If you only see 1 `*` something else is wrong.

Comment: code surrounding it shouldn't matter. It works on one machine and not another is the issue.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the drop of the 3rd parameter. Thanks for your help programmers!

Comment: Perhaps you could have read the docs and/or google a bit **before** posting on SO...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third param of `strstr` was introduced in PHP 5.3.0 so you cannot use this param in your remote server which has PHP 5.2.x

Link here http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php (notice the **Change log** section)

Comment: Tested it in my computer, warning and nothing else. Maybe the author server has been config to hide all PHP warning so he see nothing.

Comment: I just tested it myself, it always returns null when you don't provide the right amount of arguments.